# How can I know if the checkbox is checked when all the fields have unique id?

Tags: javascript, html, checkbox

To know if the checkbox has been checked or not, I have been calling this function. *(when the user click submit button)* `delete_checkbox` is the `id` of the checkbox field that is being checked.

```
function ifChecked() {
   if(!document.getElementById("delete_checkbox").checked) 
        alert("Select the tweet!");
}
```

How can I check when the `id` of the checkbox is generated dynamically ? For example :

```
<input type="checkbox" id="1" />
<input type="checkbox" id="78" />
```

For the above 2 fields, how can the above function be modified when the user clicks the `submit` button ?

Comment: [querySelectorAll](https://developer.mozilla.org/en-US/docs/Web/API/Document.querySelectorAll)?

Comment: are you checking for ANY checkbox? or a checkbox within a container of a specific id?

Comment: @BrettWeber for a checkbox

Comment: Get a list of all the checkboxes with `querySelectorAll`, then iterate over them to see if any are not checked.

Comment: Where's the ID you're targeting, and where is the function called? It's all just random code!

Comment: Is that a specific checkbox or all checkboxes?

Comment: @adeneo It is called as the `submit` button is clicked

Comment: And how would we know that? What element matches that ID etc ?

Comment: @Barmar: or he could use `querySelectorAll()` to find *only* the checked checkboxes: `document.querySelectorAll('input[type="checkbox"]:checked')` (assuming browsers that implement querySelectorAll() also implant the `:checked` pseudo-class).

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Give each of the checkboxes the same `name`. The `<form>` tag as a property called `elements` which gives you access to all the fields within the form.

```
<form ... onsubmit="foo(event, this);">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_me" id="1">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_me" id="2">
    <input type="checkbox" name="delete_me" id="3">

    <button type="submit">Submit</button>
</form>
```

Then some JavaScript:

```
function foo(event, form) {
    event.preventDefault(); // keep form from submitting

    var deleteCheckboxes = form.elements.delete_me;

    for (var i = 0; i < deleteCheckboxes.length; i++) {
        if (deleteCheckboxes[i].checked) {
            console.log(deleteCheckboxes[i].id + " is checked");
        }
    }
}
```

Answer (score 0):

If you want to know if there are any unchecked checkboxes:

```
if (document.querySelectorAll("input[type=checkbox]:not(:checked)").length > 0) {
    alert("Please select all the tweets!");
}
```